# Smart pointer for single owner and multiple references

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Back in the days I implemented linked lists and trees using raw pointers. When I tried to implement using smart pointers I came upon the following problem as I don’t know what to use for a pointer that will have only one owner but 0 or more references:

For an example lets take a binary tree:

For starters the nodes should be the only ‘owners’ of the pointers: the nodes live and die with the tree, so to me it makes sense to make them `unique_ptr` and not `shared_ptr`:

```
class Tree {
  std::unique_ptr<Node> root_;
}

class Node {
  std::unique_ptr<Node> left_child_, right_child_;
}
```

And then I had to make an algorithm like that:

```
Node * node = root_.get(); // <-- what type should node be??
while(node) {
  if (node->left_count < node->right_count) {
    node = node->left_child_.get();
  } else {
    node = node->right_child.get();
  }
}
// do something on node
```

But I don’t like using raw pointers. So what kind of smart pointer `node` should be? The idea is that it should have no ownership over the pointer. I read that `weak_ptr` — which looks like what I want — works only with `shared_ptr`, but again I think that there is no need of the overhead of `shared_ptr` here. At any point in time there will be one and only one owner.

Along the same lines for a linked list:

```
class LinkedList {
  std::unique_ptr<Node> first_;
  /** ?? type ?? **/ last_;
}


for (/*?? type ??*/ n = first_; n != last_; n = n->next) {
}
```

**edit**

The reason why I don’t like using raw pointers (beyond the point of not using them anymore in C++) is let’s say I want to expose them to the outside (via interface): it should be clear that they should not be freed. A `smart pointer` should be the smart choice here.

Comment: Raw pointers seem like the correct thing to use here... it's exactly what you're looking for -- a pointer with no ownership semantics yet that can still be referred to. Is there a reason you want to avoid them?

Comment: weak_ptr is indeed the abstraction you're describing. It's defined as a non-owning smart_ptr. It has the benefit of avoiding the risk of a dangling invalid pointer, because a weak_ptr is notified when the underlying object is freed. But if you can avoid having any invalid raw pointers hanging around in other ways, then you don't need the overhead of the weak_ptr and smart_ptr.

Comment: You want just an observing pointer not involved in ownership. There is currently no abstraction for that in the standard library, but maybe we'll see something like http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3514.pdf one day.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: `weak_ptr` isn't that?

Comment: @alecbenzer: Manual memory management, ugh

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit does `weak_ptr` work with `unique_ptr`?

Comment: `weak_ptr` works here, but then you cannot use a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @bolov: On a more serious note, if you use smart pointers throughout your implementation and interfaces it might be pretty clear that any raw pointers are just dumb observers which shouldn't be free'd manually (and add a comment clarifying this to you and everybody else).

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: Okay; that's too bad :(

Comment: The reason that `weak_ptr` doesn't work with `unique_ptr` is that if you want "`weak_ptr` works with FOO" to be true, then FOO needs to have logic to invalidate weak pointers when the object is destroyed. `unique_ptr` is designed to be really cheap (so that people who care about performance actually use it), so it doesn't do that sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are over engineering here. It should be fine that the external clients consume a raw pointer as long as they respect the fact they are not involved in the object lifetime. If you really want to be purist then you would need to use shared_ptr and return weak_ptr. Notice that you might actually need to do anyway that because in order to construct or maintain your data structure the internal pointer might need to be shared temporarily.

Another option is to use unique_ptr in the data structure and create your own custom smart pointer that consumes the raw pointer returned by unique_ptr::get. I think a good name would be proxy_ptr and could even have something like: proxy_ptr p = make_proxy(yourUniquePtr.get());